# How can I access a variable outside of a function in ReactNative?

Tags: reactjs, function, variables, react-hooks, native

I have a settings page in my app that has settings that I want to be able to access to modify another page. This is the settings page:

```
const Settings = () => {
  const [isSwitchOn, setIsSwitchOn] = React.useState(false);
  const onToggleSwitch = () => setIsSwitchOn(!isSwitchOn);
  const [themeSwitchOn, setThemeSwitchOn] = React.useState(false);
  const onToggleThemeSwitch = () => setThemeSwitchOn(!themeSwitchOn);
  const SettingsDisplay = ({darkMode}) => (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: darkMode ? "#121212" : "aliceblue" }}>
      <Text style={[styles.label, { color: darkMode ? "white" : "black" }]}>Settings</Text>
      <View style={styles.testRow}>
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: "60%", color: darkMode ? "white" : "black" }}>Toggle Theme</Text>
        <Switch color="#006ee6" value={themeSwitchOn} onValueChange={onToggleThemeSwitch} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.testRow}>
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: "60%", color: darkMode ? "white" : "black" }}>Toggle Display</Text>
        <Switch color="#006ee6" value={isSwitchOn} onValueChange={onToggleSwitch} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
  return(
    <SettingsDisplay darkMode={themeSwitchOn ? true : false}></SettingsDisplay>
  )
}
```

And I'd like to access the values for "isSwitchOn" and "themeSwitchOn" in another const. How can I do that?

Edit: Here is the code in the other function:

```
const Home = ({navigation}) => {
`lots of code`
  if (!Settings.isSwitchOn) {
    return <CardDisplay label="Card Display" options={info.details} darkMode={Settings.themeSwitchOn ? true : false}></CardDisplay>
  } else if (Settings.isSwitchOn) {
    return <CompactDisplay label="Compact Display" options={info.details} darkMode={Settings.themeSwitchOn ? true : false}></CompactDisplay>
  }
};
```

Comment: Where is the other component being rendered?

Comment: In the same App.js file, it's just in another const (the home page of the app). I want it to update live whenever the switch is flipped in the Settings page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you don't have understanding of React Native Components and state management! if you are beginner then I will suggest you first understand basics React Native components and state management, but if you are comfortable with basic fundamentals the you can pass your values to another components using props and second method is using context APIs or other state management libraries/frameworks like React Redux etc,

you can use following method to pass your values using props

```
const Settings = () => {
...
<AnotherComponent isSwitchOn={isSwitchOn} themeSwitchOn={themeSwitchOn} />
...
}

const AnotherComponent = ({isSwitchOn, themeSwitchOn}) => {
...
// here you can access your props
...
}
```

Comment: This is not my problem, I have another function of which I'd like to change the settings from the "settings" function. I do not want to call the other function inside "Settings" because it is a different page entirely.